# unit of messurement table is required if there i'm going to store two record in database

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

In my e-commerce application there are several products available in two units 
i.e. product "X" has two types of packaging

1. 200 gram
2. 400 gram

Is there any need for creating `Unit_Of_Mesurement` table? If not then what is the solution or is there any other solution?

Comment: No, It can't be needed , it is managed on user side.

Comment: It depends on if you need to search this data, if you don't need to search it you could store it as JSON, but if you do need to search on that then a table may be a better option.

Comment: thankx for reply yes, i need the units for generating different reports. than i should create separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an e-commerce site where a given product may be sold in different packages, you can either have each product package stored as a separate product, or use a second table to store the different formats of the product, where the rest of the generic product info is taken from a main product table.

For example, you'd have a *product* table, that contains information that applies to the product regardless of which format is being considered:

```
ID | name      | brand
--------------------------
 1 | Product 1 | ACME Corp
 2 | product 2 | ACME Corp
```

And then you'd have a *product_format* table, which contains the different packaging variations that product might have. If a product isn't sold in any different formats, then you could just have a single row here that contains the price, without specifying the format, since you won't need to show that information.

```
ID | product_ID | format | price
----------------------------------
 1 | 1          | 200g   | 19.99
 2 | 1          | 400g   | 37.99
 3 | 2          | null   | 8.99
```

Comment: Thanx.. I'm little bit confused for example. customer purchase product 1 and product 2 (simultaneously)  what will be the entry for sales_order and sales_detail?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your sales tables, but you should have a table that contains a row for each item in a customer's order. In this case, instead of saving the product ID, you would save the product_format ID.